# Edit DCOM protocols programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server, dcom

I need to automate a manipulation through powershell, but I just don't know how to do so.

Here is the manual procedure:

1. Click on "Component Services":

[image: Click on "Component Services"]

2. Click on "Property" of the computer

[image: Click on "Property" of the computer]

3. Click on "Property" of the "TCP/IP connexion"

[image: Click on "Property" of the "TCP/IP connexion"]

4. Add a port range

[image: Add a port range]

5. Enter a port range, then hit "OK"

[image: Enter a port range, then hit "OK"]

I searched for quite a while online, and got some clues on how to do access the related WMI Object, but from there, I am stuck. I used trial and error to no avail.

If anyone has ever done this, or know more about it, I would be glad to know it.

Comment: If you're gonna add pictures don't add them as links, embed them with the picture button.

Comment: I simply cannot, I "need 10 reputation". I am new here, so I guess the website does not allow me to do it

Answer (score 0):

Registry Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet
ValueName: Ports
Type: REG_MULTI_SZ

Example export of the key from Regedit.exe, from Windows Server 2016, for ports: 60001-61248:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet]
"PortsInternetAvailable"="N"
"UseInternetPorts"="N"
"Ports"=hex(7):36,00,30,00,30,00,30,00,31,00,2d,00,36,00,31,00,32,00,34,00,38,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

A link describing these settings in more detail is:
[How to configure RPC dynamic port allocation to work with firewalls](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154596/how-to-configure-rpc-dynamic-port-allocation-to-work-with-firewalls)

I originally found a hint to this registry key on this web page: [Troubleshooting RPC Endpoint Mapper errors using the Windows Server 2003 Support Tools from the product CD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839880/troubleshooting-rpc-endpoint-mapper-errors-using-the-windows-server-20)